# What is this ほれ?

Tags: grammar, words

> まるでこの場から──つまりはシンから──引き離すようにそそくさと去っていくレーナを、釈然としないままシンは見送る。去り際にベルノルトが振り返って**ほれ**とばかりに片手を出してきたので、用無しになった制帽を渡した。
>
> 86─エイティシックス─Ep.4　─アンダー・プレッシャー─ 安里アサト

What does this ほれ mean? Is it the imperative form of 掘る? But that doesn’t appear to make sense in this context.

Answer (score 3):

It’s a variation of [ほら](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BB%E3%82%89), an interjection used to draw someone’s attention to something or urge someone to do something.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is probably easier if there was a comma:

ベルノルトが振り返って「、」ほれとばかりに片手を出してきた

Then you can see that the second part is: 「ほれ」**とばかりに**片手を出してきた

Where you can see ほれ is used quotatively. ほれ means the same as [ほら](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BB%E3%82%8C)